# NullPointerException won't go away

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I've been trying to figure out what my problem is for so long but I honestly can not figure out how to fix this error, and until I fix this one I can't check the rest of my program to see if it works.

I'm building a program that allows you to input a .txt file that contains characters that make up a maze (# = walls, . = path, S = start, G = goal), and using recursion the computer finds a path through the maze and prints a solution.

It keeps saying I'm getting a NullPointerException error at line 32. I've tried initializing the array differently, tried initializing it outside of the loop, but I really am stumped. I would appreciate any help I could get! Here is my entire code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

// MUST BE 10X5 ARRAY 
public class TheMaze {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //input the text file. test.txt should be whatever your maze is
    String inputDoc = "test.txt";
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(inputDoc);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);



    //if your maze has dimensions different than 10x5, change these x and y values accordingly
    int x = 10;
    int y = 5;
    char [][] maze = new char [x][y];
    int xPosition = 0;
    int yPosition = 0;

    //now... to get the string into the 2d char array.
    for (int rows = 0; rows < maze.length; rows++) {

        String thisLineString;
        char thisLineArray[] = new char [x];
        thisLineString = br.readLine();
        thisLineArray = thisLineString.toCharArray();

        for (int columns = 0; columns < maze[0].length; columns++) {

            maze[rows][columns] = thisLineArray[columns];

        }   

    }

    //find starting position
    for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < maze[0].length; j++) {

            if (maze[i][j] == 'S') {

                xPosition = i;
                yPosition = j;

            }

        }
    }


    // i dont think this actually does anything because we end up printing the solved maze withib the function. cant make
    //it a void because that would mess up the recursion stuff going on
    char randomArray [][] = FindPath(maze , xPosition, yPosition);




}


public static char [][] FindPath( char [][]maze, int xPosition, int yPosition) {

    //first if to see if inbounds
    if (0 <= xPosition && maze.length > xPosition && 0 <= yPosition && maze[0].length > yPosition) {

        if (maze[xPosition][yPosition] == 'G') {
            //solution found ,

            // FIGURE OUT HOW TO print solved maze

            //using for loops you kind of reverse engineer what you did putting it from a string to 2d char array
            for (int one = 0; one < maze.length; one++) {
                //resets the line after it's printed, first time around this does nothing
                String lineOfMaze = "";

                for (int two = 0; two < maze[0].length; two++) {

                    lineOfMaze = lineOfMaze + maze[one][two];
                }


            }

            return maze;

        } else if (maze[xPosition][yPosition] == '#') {

            // wall
            return maze; 

        } else if (maze[xPosition][yPosition] == '+') {
            //already been here

            return maze;
        } else if (maze[xPosition][yPosition] == 'S' || maze[xPosition][yPosition] == '.'){
            //when youre at the start, or on an open path

            if (maze[xPosition][yPosition] == '.') {

                //marks the spot as part of the path
                maze[xPosition][yPosition] = '+';

            }
            if (FindPath(maze, xPosition, yPosition+1) != maze) {
                //checks to the north

                return maze;
            } else if (FindPath(maze, xPosition+1, yPosition) != maze) {
                //checks east

                return maze;
            } else if (FindPath(maze, xPosition, yPosition-1) != maze) {
                //check south

                return maze;
            } else if (FindPath(maze, xPosition-1, yPosition) != maze) {
                //checks west

                return maze;
            } else {
                // no path found, start backtracking and remove this spot as being a place on the path, unless youre still at the start
                //in which case it just doesn't do anything
                if (maze[xPosition][yPosition] == '+') {

                        maze[xPosition][yPosition] = '.';

                }

                return maze;
            }


        }


    }
    return maze; 
}
```

}

The line where the error is is thisLineArray = thisLineString.toCharArray();, and again it is a NullPointerException error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somehow, all mazes have NPE.

Comment: Looks like your stream has reached its end - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: You should check the value of `br.readLine()` , because it will be null as soon as there is no more line to read in the file .

Comment: If you're getting an error at `thisLineArray = thisLineString.toCharArray();`, then `thisLineString` is null, meaning that there's nothing more to read.

Comment: Check line endings, they must be \n, \r or \r\n.